Magnifying Glass Effect "failing" at edges
I'm trying to build a magnifying glass effect. This is where, when you move the cursor over an image, a magnified (ie larger) part of the image underneath the cursor is shown. I've gotten close with my coding. An example of what I have is this:


    let zoom = 2;

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const image = document.querySelector('.image'),
        { width, height } = image.getBoundingClientRect(),
        glass = document.createElement('div');

      document.querySelector('.image-wrapper').append(glass);
      glass.classList.add('glass');
      glass.style.backgroundSize = `${zoom * width}px ${zoom * height}px`;
      glass.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image.src})`;

      image.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        const { offsetX, offsetY } = e,
          glassX = offsetX - glass.offsetWidth / 2,
          glassY = offsetY - glass.offsetHeight / 2;

        glass.style.left = `${glassX}px`;
        glass.style.top = `${glassY}px`;

        glass.style.backgroundPosition = `-${offsetX * zoom}px -${offsetY * zoom}px`;
      });
    });
   body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    .image-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px dashed gray;
    }

    .image {
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
      cursor: none;
    }

    .image-wrapper .glass {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .image-wrapper:hover .glass {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .glass {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: none;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JzS3fR2C.jpg" alt="Sample Image" style="opacity: 0.1;" class="image">
  </div>



The source image is this

While the magnifying glass mostly works it "fails" around the edges. When the cursor gets to the edge of the image I want the glass to show a "semi circle" of the image with the other semi being white. That is I want this:

but I get this

How to fix this so that it behaves itself around all 4 edges?

Note that you can do all these computations without JS:  CSS can run them much faster (and more responsively, as JS will block page handling, whereas CSS won't)

I'm interested, can you show me how CSS could do this?

Oh, the page I was viewing hadn't updated to show your answer. Thanks I'll look into it.

Based on your approach, I made two tweaks to fix the issue:

Define glassSize property so you could use it in both CSS and JavaScript calculations:

// glass size, in px
const glassSize = 100;

// assign the CSS variable to .image-wrapper
document.querySelector('.image-wrapper').style.setProperty('--glass-size', `${glassSize}px`)

.glass {
  /* use variable instead of hardcoded 100px */
  width: var(--glass-size);
  height: var(--glass-size);
}


Add the correct offset to the background position of .glass.

glass.style.backgroundPosition = `${-(offsetX * zoom - glassSize / 2)}px ${-(offsetY * zoom - glassSize / 2)}px`;

You want the offset of the background position to be offset by half of the glassSize, so the edges of the image can be offset correctly.
Notice it's better to put the negative sign inside of calculation: ${-(x)} instead of -${x}, so when x became a negative value (e.g. -42), the -${x} won't become something like --42 which is not going be interpreted correctly.


let zoom = 2;
const glassSize = 100;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const image = document.querySelector('.image'),
    {
      width,
      height
    } = image.getBoundingClientRect(),
    glass = document.createElement('div');

  document.querySelector('.image-wrapper').append(glass);
  document.querySelector('.image-wrapper').style.setProperty('--glass-size', `${glassSize}px`)
  glass.classList.add('glass');
  glass.style.backgroundSize = `${zoom * width}px ${zoom * height}px`;
  glass.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image.src})`;

  image.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const {
      offsetX,
      offsetY
    } = e,
    glassX = offsetX - glass.offsetWidth / 2,
      glassY = offsetY - glass.offsetHeight / 2;

    glass.style.left = `${glassX}px`;
    glass.style.top = `${glassY}px`;

    glass.style.backgroundPosition = `${-(offsetX * zoom - glassSize / 2)}px ${-(offsetY * zoom - glassSize / 2)}px`;
  });
});
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.image {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: none;
}

.image-wrapper .glass {
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .glass {
  opacity: 1;
}

.glass {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--glass-size);
  height: var(--glass-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JzS3fR2C.jpg" alt="Sample Image" style="opacity: 0.1;" class="image">
</div>




Page layout note: most of the calculations that you're currently doing in JS in order to calculate layout positioning and sizing can be done purely in CSS using variables and calc() expressions, requiring drastically less JS while also running faster.
Working your own solution into the code, but implementing things with CSS rather than JS, gives us:


const zoom = 2;
const image = document.querySelector('.image');
image.onload = function addSpyGlass() {
  const { width, height } = image.getBoundingClientRect()

  // Let's do as _little_ as possible here: get the values,
  // hand them over to CSS, and do literally nothing else:

  const glass = document.createElement('div');
  glass.classList.add('glass');

  const { style } = glass;
  style.setProperty(`--w`, width);
  style.setProperty(`--h`, height);
  style.setProperty(`--zoom`, zoom);
  style.setProperty(`--src`, `url(${image.src}`);

  image.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ offsetX, offsetY}) => {
    style.setProperty(`--x`, offsetX);
    style.setProperty(`--y`, offsetY);
    // That's it. That's all we do.
  });

  image.parentNode.append(glass);
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;

  .image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px dashed gray;

    .image {
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
      cursor: none;
      opacity: 0.1;
    }

    &:hover .glass {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    /*
      let's do some math in CSS instead.
      I prefer to keep my CSS variables
      unit-less so I can quickly rewrite
      things if I need to, but you can 
      bake in the unit if you don't want
      those "... * 1px" everywhere, of course.
    */

    .glass {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: none;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      --d: 100;
      --d2: calc(var(--d) / 2);
      width: calc(var(--d) * 1px);
      height: calc(var(--d) * 1px);

      --x: 0;
      --y: 0;
      --left: calc((var(--x) - var(--d2)) * 1px);
      --top: calc((var(--y) - var(--d2)) * 1px);
      transform: translate(var(--left), var(--top));

      --src: "";
      background-image: var(--src);

      --w: 0;
      --h: 0;
      --zoom: 2;
      background-size:
        calc(var(--zoom) * var(--w) * 1px)
        calc(var(--zoom) * var(--h) * 1px);

      --bg-x: calc(0 - (var(--x) * var(--zoom) - var(--d2)));
      --bg-y: calc(0 - (var(--y) * var(--zoom) - var(--d2)));
      background-position:
        calc(var(--bg-x) * 1px)
        calc(var(--bg-y) * 1px);
    }
  }
}
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JzS3fR2C.jpg" alt="Sample Image" class="image">
</div>



That said, as a user it'd be nicer to have the spyglass pop up "close to" rather than "over" the image (e.g. based on mousemove over the image-wrapper rather than the image, with a calc(var(--d) / 2 * 1px) padding to get that buffer around the image itself).

Superb answer; good call on the use of CSS. However, because you're using left/top, this is still going to use the main thread for layouting. To get buttery smooth performance, express as transform: translate() offsets. See: https://web.dev/articles/animations-overview

Busted! You're spot on, and excellent link, too: transforms are the real ticket. CSS updated accordingly =D

So fast! Nice one.

The issue you're seeing is that the background of glass isn't aligned correctly.
The glass div is positioned from its top-left corner. Your code corrects for this by subtracting half of glass's width and height when calculating its new position:
glassX = offsetX - glass.offsetWidth / 2,
glassY = offsetY - glass.offsetHeight / 2;

However, the background-position is also positioned relative to the top-left corner of glass. If the top-left corner were at the same position as the cursor, this would work great. But remember that you corrected glass's position above so the cursor would be at its center. Therefore, you'll need to move the background-position "back" to where it would be.
So when you're calculating background-positon:
glass.style.backgroundPosition = `-${offsetX * zoom}px -${offsetY * zoom}px`;

you need to add glass.offsetWidth / 2 and glass.offsetHeight / 2 back in:
glass.style.backgroundPosition = `-${offsetX * zoom - glass.offsetWidth / 2}px -${offsetY * zoom - glass.offsetHeight / 2}px`;

But wait! The expressions you're using in your template string could produce negative numbers when near the top or left edges of the image! Since you included a - in the template string, this would generate something like --13.2px..., which isn't valid CSS.
This is a simple fix, however. Just move the negation inside the expression, like so:
glass.style.backgroundPosition = `${-offsetX * zoom + glass.offsetWidth / 2}px ${-offsetY * zoom + glass.offsetHeight / 2}px`;

Now we won't generate invalid CSS.
Working snippet:


let zoom = 2;

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const image = document.querySelector('.image'),
        { width, height } = image.getBoundingClientRect(),
        glass = document.createElement('div');

      document.querySelector('.image-wrapper').append(glass);
      glass.classList.add('glass');
      glass.style.backgroundSize = `${zoom * width}px ${zoom * height}px`;
      glass.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image.src})`;

      image.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        const { offsetX, offsetY } = e,
          glassX = offsetX - glass.offsetWidth / 2,
          glassY = offsetY - glass.offsetHeight / 2;

        glass.style.left = `${glassX}px`;
        glass.style.top = `${glassY}px`;

        glass.style.backgroundPosition = `${-offsetX * zoom + glass.offsetWidth / 2}px ${-offsetY * zoom + glass.offsetHeight / 2}px`;
      });
    });
body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    .image-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px dashed gray;
    }

    .image {
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
      cursor: none;
    }

    .image-wrapper .glass {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .image-wrapper:hover .glass {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .glass {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: none;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JzS3fR2C.jpg" alt="Sample Image" style="opacity: 0.1;" class="image">
  </div>




Why was this downvoted? I think I've answered the question better than the one by the OP (& explained the issues in the code). Feedback would be appreciated, please.

Because I have a feeling this is also GPT-created - Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

Honestly, it's not. I see how you could read my writing style as that though. Is there anything I can do to convince you? For example, please note that my code actually works whereas the GPT stuff below doesn't look like it will.

After some gnashing of teeth I got it to work by changing the mousemove event's code to:
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e,
          gw = glass.offsetWidth / 2,
          gh = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

    glass.style.left = `${offsetX - gw}px`;
    glass.style.top  = `${offsetY - gh}px`;

    const x = -Math.floor((offsetX / width)  * (width * zoom)  - gw),
          y = -Math.floor((offsetY / height) * (height * zoom) - gh);
    
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = `${x}px ${y}px`;


Math time: note that the parentheses in your (offsetX / width)  * (width * zoom) don't matter, it's really just offsetX / width * width * zoom so you're dividing by width and then multiplying by width again: that cancels out, leaving you with offsetX * zoom.

You're right. I thought I was being clever :-(
